# Linq method Sum not supported in .NET 7 generic math?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-7.0

I have the following code, but it does not compile in Visual Studio 17.4 preview 2.1 and .NET 7 RC1 SDK:

```
using System.Numerics;

int averageInt = Average<int, int>(1, 5, 10);
Console.WriteLine(averageInt);

double averageDouble = Average<int, double>(1, 5, 10);
Console.WriteLine(averageDouble);

TResult Average<TInput, TResult>(params TInput[] numbers)
    where TInput : INumber<TInput>
    where TResult : INumber<TResult> => numbers.Sum() / TResult.CreateChecked(numbers.Length);
```

The compiler error I get is:
`Error  CS1929  'TInput[]' does not contain a definition for 'Sum' and the best extension method overload 'Queryable.Sum(IQueryable<decimal>)' requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable<decimal>'`

I tried the following as an alternative, but it also doesn't compile:

```
using System.Numerics;

int averageInt = Average<int, int>(1, 5, 10);
Console.WriteLine(averageInt);

double averageDouble = Average<int, double>(1, 5, 10);
Console.WriteLine(averageDouble);

TResult Average<TInput, TResult>(params TInput[] numbers)
    where TInput : INumber<TInput>
    where TResult : INumber<TResult> => numbers.AsQueryable().Sum() / TResult.CreateChecked(numbers.Length);
```

With the error:
`Error  CS1929  'IQueryable<TInput>' does not contain a definition for 'Sum' and the best extension method overload 'Queryable.Sum(IQueryable<decimal>)' requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable<decimal>'`

What am I missing here?

Comment: Related?: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/64031

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ATM there is no overload for [`Enumerable.Sum`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum?view=net-7.0) (as for `Max`, `Min` etc.) leveraging the generic math. For now you can work around using [`Enumerable.Aggregate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate?view=net-7.0):

```cs
TResult Average<TInput, TResult>(params TInput[] numbers)
    where TInput : INumber<TInput>
    where TResult : INumber<TResult> 
    => numbers.Aggregate(TResult.Zero, (agg, t) => agg + TResult.CreateChecked(t)) 
          / TResult.CreateChecked(numbers.Length);
```

The same approach can be used for other similar operations.

For build in support - monitor [this github](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/64031) issue.